# How to select a class initiated with innerHTML inside of the same function

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    test[i].innerHTML += '<div class="testClass">';
    for (var j = 0; j < this.length; j++) {
        var testClass = ???????;
    }
}
```

How can I select testClass element that was initialized in innerHTML?

Comment: How about `var testClass = document.getElementsByClassName('testClass')[i];`?

Comment: You cant use `document.getElement` since the div is not in the DOM.

Comment: @CristianS. Why does it work in jsfiddle then?

Comment: @CristianS. it is in the dom at this point but I agree it's not the best way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `document.createElement()` instead of `innerHTML`, it's much better optimized.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'testClass';
    test[i].appendChild(div);
    for (var j = 0; j < this.length; j++) {
        // do whatever you want with the <DIV>
    }
}
```

Read up on HTML DOM and its related interfaces (such as `HTMLElement`) on MDN; they are much more efficient and manageable than relying on `innerHTML`.